# tkinter raising windows over each other with place

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, desktop-application

I want to make a simple app that switches windows whenever I pressed a button, the project was based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7518203), it worked very well using this code, However, when I tried to use `place` as well as other modifications.

<s>The app stopped switching windows and it shows both canvases in the same window</s>
The App shows no buttons at all just a blank screen, Here is the code. Anyone came across something like this!?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F,name in zip([page1, page2],
                       ["page1", "page2"]):
            frame = F(parent=self.container, controller=self)
            self.frames[name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.pack_propagate(False)

        self.show_frame("page1")

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller


        f = tk.Frame(self)
        f.place(in_=self, anchor='c', relx=.5, rely=.5)
        C1=tk.LabelFrame(f,text=' TEST PAGE 1! ',font=('Arial',13,'bold'), bg="blue")
        C1.place(relheight=.2, relwidth=.9)
        C=tk.Frame(C1,height=60,width=40)
        C.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

        button1=tk.Button(C,text="page2"
                            ,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page2"))
        button1.place(width=400,height=70)

class page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller

        f = tk.Frame(self)
        f.place(in_=self, anchor='c', relx=.5, rely=.5)
        C1=tk.LabelFrame(f,text=' TEST PAGE 2! ',font=('Arial',13,'bold'), bg="blue")
        C1.place(relheight=.2, relwidth=.9)
        C=tk.Frame(C1,height=60,width=40)
        C.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=3)

        button1=tk.Button(C,text="page1"
                            ,command=lambda: controller.show_frame("page1"))
        button1.place(width=200,height=70)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.geometry("1200x720+0+0")
    app.resizable(False, False)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `C` is not what you're assuming it is.

Comment: what do you mean, it's just a frame where the button is.

Comment: Add `print(C)` and you will know what Bryan means.

Comment: I'm an idiot!! thanks to you acw1668 and Bryan, I edited it